# What is the physics behind the high damping capacity of magnesium?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, metals, material-science

the definition of Damping Capacity is:

"The ability of metal to absorb energy (stress energy) by converting it into heat” .And I cannot interpret why some metals absorb the applied stress energy on them and the other metals not !! So I cannot understand this definition.

Comment: Where does your definition come from?

Comment: Google for "Granato-Lücke damping theory".

Comment: Dear Mr @Gert , follow this link ,please
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_capacity .
And  http://www.atlasfdry.com/grayiron-damping.htm . But in the later one I'm confused between Damping Capacity and Electromagnetic Shielding!!

Comment: @alephzero Yes Sir, I will do it immediately.
 Regards,